# Django how to define permissions so users can only edit certain model hierarchies?

Tags: python, django, permissions, user-permissions

If I have models like this..

```
class Family(Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Father(Model):
    family = ForeignKey(Family)

class Mother(Model):
    family = ForeignKey(Family)

class Child(Model):
    family = ForeignKey(Family)
```

Django makes group permissions automatically so I can define groups that can edit/create/etc... the family model.

How can I limit it to only let a user edit a certain instance of the family model? So if I want the 'Johnson' family admin to only have permission to edit things under the 'Johnson' family tree.

I can think of two ways, one would be defining a custom permission like (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) but I have no idea what the docs are saying there and they do not do a good job of explaining it.

I can also think of possibly adding a field on the user model and checking the value of that, but it feels wrong to do it that way...

Comment: I believe Django's permission system is not cabable of doing this (not sure). Personally, I would just check from the user model when trying to modify the family models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine two ways for achieving what you want, but that'd be experimental and I don't know if it would follow the good practices :

### 1 - [Programmatically created permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions) :

With codename partially based on the instance.
For example, creating a permission with a codename containing the instance the user could edit :

```
perm = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_create_'+str(obj.id),
                                 name='can edit instance with id ' + str(obj.id))
user.user_permissions.add(perm)
```

and then :

```
if user.has_perm('can_create_' + str(relevant_id)):
```

### 2 - [ManyToMany relationships as permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) :

Probably the field idea you had yourself :

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    editors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='mymodel_can_edit')
```

and then just add and remove the instances a user can delete in its `mymodel_can_edit` field just like you manage the permissions in its `user_permissions` field.

But I didn't test any of these solution.
If you try it could you tell what you think about it? :)

Comment: I ended up using option 2 and then adding some logic to the CBV dispatch method to check if they have permission, returning a 403 if they don't

Answer (score 0):

You can use django modules that provide this functionality.
I personally use [django-guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian) which offers per-object permissions using an interface similar to the original `has_perm` method.